# Default X Axis position of highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I have a linar chart on Highchart.lib. I am showing more than zero values on it. How can i move X Axis to the bottom, because i dont need less then zero values. See attach.[image]

Answer (score 2):

I assume from your image that you mean the y axis.

Easiest way is to simply set your y axis min and max values.
You can also work with the startOnTick and minPadding settings for a variety of control options.

http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#yAxis

Comment: Thank you, I already see that, but set min and max option separate. Now all works well)

Answer (score 0):

set min Value and minRange Value  - thats it.

Comment: min : 0,minRange:  /*minimal expected value here*/